# Sharing a file from Dropbox in Win10: Cannot provide edit permissions?

Tags: permissions, dropbox

I have a file in my Dropbox local folder on my Win10 Laptop. In explorer if I Right Click I get a context menu option to "Dropbox->Share". This allows me to enter an email address of a contact to share the file with.

However the permission seems to be only "Can View" and there's a dropdown so I assume there must be a way to select "Edit" as well. But somehow that option is not available for me. (See screenshot).

Any thoughts what I may be doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: [per DropBox Forum](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-files-folders/Can-edit-option-does-not-appear-when-sharing-file/td-p/271667#:~:text=Re%3A%20Can%20edit%20option%20does%20not%20appear%20when%20sharing%20file&text=The%20ability%20to%20edit%20is,folder%20and%20share%20the%20folder.) - you need to share the folder to be able to edit the files (for MS Office files) all other files can not be edited - yours is a PDF - so view only

Comment: @Zina Oh!! Thanks. So does that mean there's no way to selectively share files from a folder with a collaborator for editing? One MUST share the whole folder?!

Comment: see my edit - only MSO files can be edited...no matter if you shared file only or folder...